# error while inserting the audio file in database

Tags: asp.net, database, c#-4.0

```
 str = "INSERT INTO reg (Name,ContentType,Data) values (?,?,?)"
        Try
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, dbcon)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", "chillax")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContentType", "audio")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data",     System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("E:\chillax.wav"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("inserted")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("notWorking")
        End Try
```

well, above code is not working(Data - binary datatype)

can anyone know wats wrong in tat code

Comment: So what is the error? Also at the places of ? you should write, parameter name look here to know how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: sry , i phrased it wrong, above code caught the exception (not working)

Comment: just check the example in the MSDN link to know how to use parameters with value etc

Comment: thnks yaar , it worked :)